# how can we write the code 3 classes for one div at a time?

Tags: css

I have one `<div>`, and 3 classes like `.test1`, `.test2`, `.test3`.

How can we write the code 3 classes for one div at a time?

Comment: i dont get what you mean, if you want to assign three classes to a single div then just do `<div class="text1 test2 test3"></div>`

Comment: This is "not a real question", there's 3 or 4 different ways to interpret it.  If the question ever gets clarified, it would then no doubt be a **duplicate of several other questions on this site.**

Comment: @BrockAdams : at least he got 3 or 4 different answers ;) ... sometimes it's very difficult to make yourself clear when you are not an English native speaker (I'm not) so let's give the OP a chance to get help. My five cents.

Comment: @JFK, I'm all for helping newbies, even ones who can't phrase a question well (in English).  But no matter how this question is interpreted, the answer is a very quick search away.  It's a duplicate, and if it was clear, we would know which other questions it was a duplicate of. ... This OP seems to have put no effort into finding an answer, nor formulating the question.

Comment: @BrockAdams : agree ... he showed little effort. Let's vote to close the question then. On the other hand, I found interesting how everybody interpreted and answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="test1 test2 test3"></div>
```

From what I understand, this seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have put three different classes with three different contents but want to apply the same style then have a look at this: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eQ9zp/)

HTML:

```
<div class="test1">
  Hey
</div>
<div class="test2">
  Heyy
</div>
<div class="test3">
  Heyyy
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .test1, .test2, .test3 {
  font: 20px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Or if you want something else like applying three classes to a div then woutr_be's answer is another option.

Sorry, mate but couldn't understand your question completely.

Answer (score 1):

```
   .test1{
    font-weight:bold;
    }   

   .test2{
    font-size:26px;
   }

   .test3{
    text-decoration:underline;
   }

 <div class="test1 test2 test3">Text</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nqRdM/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement previous comments and answer :

From the html point of view, you can add those three classes to one `div` at a time doing

```
<div class="test1 test2 test3"></div>
```

On the other hand, to refer (with specificity) to that `div` from the css point of view you do

```
div.test1.test2.test3 {
 /* css properties here */
}
```

... no spaces or commas.

You could also have different properties for each class

```
.test1 {  font-size: 12px; } 
.test2 {  color: red; } 
.test3 {  background-color: blue; }
```

... and those properties will be applied to that `div`